# C++ Http Request fails in open state with ERROR_INVALID_STATE

Tags: c++, http, windows-7

I am trying to send an HTTP request from a C++ program.
The problem is that I get a `5023 (0x139F)` error, which is most probably `ERROR_INVALID_STATE`.
I have no idea why that happens.

It happens when I use the code from:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383989(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
and that happens when I run the line:

```
hr = pIWinHttpRequest->Open(bstrMethod,
                            bstrUrl,
                            varFalse);
```

The code is copied to here:

```
//code
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <objbase.h>

#include "httprequest.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "oleaut32.lib")
// IID for IWinHttpRequest.
const IID IID_IWinHttpRequest =
{
  0x06f29373,
  0x5c5a,
  0x4b54,
         {0xb0, 0x25, 0x6e, 0xf1, 0xbf, 0x8a, 0xbf, 0x0e}
 };

int main()
{
// Variable for return value
HRESULT    hr;

// Initialize COM
hr = CoInitialize( NULL );

IWinHttpRequest *  pIWinHttpRequest = NULL;

BSTR            bstrResponse = NULL;
VARIANT         varFalse;
VARIANT         varEmpty;

CLSID           clsid;

VariantInit(&varFalse);
V_VT(&varFalse)   = VT_BOOL;
V_BOOL(&varFalse) = VARIANT_FALSE;

VariantInit(&varEmpty);
V_VT(&varEmpty) = VT_ERROR;

hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1",
                       &clsid);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid,
                          NULL,
                          CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                          IID_IWinHttpRequest,
                          (void **)&pIWinHttpRequest);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Open WinHttpRequest.
    BSTR bstrMethod  = SysAllocString(L"GET");
    BSTR bstrUrl = SysAllocString(L"http://microsoft.com");
    hr = pIWinHttpRequest->Open(bstrMethod,
                                bstrUrl,
                                varFalse);
    SysFreeString(bstrMethod);
    SysFreeString(bstrUrl);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Send Request.
    hr = pIWinHttpRequest->Send(varEmpty);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Get Response text.
    hr = pIWinHttpRequest->get_ResponseText(&bstrResponse);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Print the response to a console.
    wprintf(L"%.256s",bstrResponse);
}

// Release memory.
if (pIWinHttpRequest)
    pIWinHttpRequest->Release();
if (bstrResponse)
    SysFreeString(bstrResponse);

CoUninitialize();
return 0;
}
```

Your help is appreciated.
I use Windows 7 64 bit if this matters in anyway.
On another machine Windows 7 64 bit machine the same code worked for me, so that must be an environment issue.
If anyone knows what to look for, it will be great.
Thanks,
Ronen